# remove class if input field empty

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the snippet provider there is a simple function which does the following.

- Looks for e-mail in the input field, and>> pushes e-mail to md5 hash, and>> generates a url of a Gravatar which is then embedded into a class via fadeIn();

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $('.email').on('change', function(){
          var hash = hex_md5($('.email').val()); 
          $('.gravatar').attr('src', 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + hash + '?s=120').addClass('gravatar-glow').fadeIn("slow");
      });
  });


  HTML Part: <img src="" class="gravatar" style="display: none;"/>
  ```

**The problem**

- If e-mail is deleted the class is still shown however this time its not using md5 of email but is displaying default Gravatar image.

What I want to achieve is if the input field is empty because say user choose to remove there e-mail to use a different one, I want to hide the class that was previously used instead of displaying a Default Gravatar image.

And here is the jQuery code

Comment: Why not use an `if` function on the email value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `toggleClass`, this method accepts a boolean value, if the switch is `true`, class is added otherwise the class is removed.

```
.toggleClass( className, switch )
```

```
$('.email').on('change', function(){
    var val = $.trim(this.value), hash = hex_md5(val); 
    $('#element').prop('src', function(){
         return val.length
                ? 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + hash + '?s=120'
                : 'default path to the image'
    }).toggleClass('.gravatar', val.length)
      .fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: Actually this still displays the default gravatar. Also class gravatar and gravatar-glow are two different classes. The gravatar-glow nearly add's a nice box-shadow to the image :) So intern I need to dispose of Gravatar class

Comment: @Cl' So you need to select the element without using `.gravatar` class, with different class or an add ID and use ID selector.